# Exercise 3.1.2, Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a ring and $\Gamma$ a finite group of automorphisms of $R$. Show that $R$ is an
> integral extension of the fixed ring $R_{\Gamma}:= \{a \in R : \gamma(a) = a\ \forall \gamma\in\gamma\}$.

It seems to me that this exercise should be done constructively, but the only intuition that I have is that, taken an element $x\in R-R_{\Gamma}$, then at least one among the (finitely many) $r_{\gamma}:=x-\gamma(x)$, as $\gamma$ varies in $\Gamma$, is non-zero. This suggest me that, when it comes to find a polynomial $f(X)\in R_\Gamma[X]$ such that $p(x)=0$, the $r_\gamma$ could be linked to the coefficients of $p(X)$. However  I really couldn't think of anything more, and any path I tried was unsuccesfull. I would just like a hint more than a solution, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered the product of $X-\gamma(x)$ over $\gamma\in \Gamma$?

Comment: @Erica do you mean the polynomial in $R[X]$ given by $\prod_{\gamma\in \Gamma}(X-\gamma(x))$? I thought of it, but I couldn't prove that its coefficients are in $R_\Gamma$; plus, if $\gamma(x)\neq x$ for all $\gamma\in \Gamma$, that polynomial doesn't have $x$ as a solution.

Comment: This polynomial is naturally invariant under the action of $\Gamma$ and then so are its coefficients. And there must be some $\gamma(x)=x$, for example if we take $\gamma$ to be the identity morphism!

Comment: @Erica I'm sorry to be this dense but I'm still confused. My first doubt is: since the identity $1_R\in\Gamma$, isn't the proposed polynomial (call it $p(X)$) always zero for every $x$? Also, I don't understand why, for every $y\in R, \alpha\in \Gamma$, we have $\alpha(p(y))=p(y)$; and even after this, I don't understand why also the coefficients must be invariant under $\Gamma$. Can you clarify it only a bit? Thank you for your patience

Comment: No, the $X$ in $p(X)$ is the variable of the polynomial, it is not the element $x\in R$, and the factor $X-1_{R}x\neq 0$! Since we take the polynomial to be $p(X)=\prod_{\gamma\in Gamma}(X-\gamma(x))$, any coefficient is a symmetric polynomial of $\{\gamma(x)|\gamma\in \Gamma\}$, which are invariant under the action of $\Gamma$.